# Why does this equality $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ not hold in this case?

Tags: probability

I have two fair six-sided dice $\Omega_1, \Omega_2= \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and I throw them both at the same time. I need to calculate the probability of getting snake eyes (a 1 on each dice) $A, B=\{1\}$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability#Independent_events) states:

> If two events, A and B are independent then the joint probability is
> $$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$$

However when I apply the formula $$P(\{1\}) \neq P(\{1\})P(\{1\})$$ $$\frac 1 6 \neq \frac 1 {36}$$
What am I doing wrong? Should I use a different sample space when calculating $P(A\cap B)$?

EDIT: The equality only holds on a valid probability space, in this case said space is ill-defined. Thanks to CyclotomicField and PMar.

Comment: Wrong probability space. You want the probability of $(1,1)$ in the cartesian product, which is $1/36$.

Comment: ty, but I still don't understand why the equality doesn't hold. Wikipedia says that if two events are mutually exclusive then $P(A\cap B) = 0$, so a requirement for the equality is $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$. I assume that another requirement is that $\Omega$ is the same in all $P(x)$. Both conditions are fulfilled, so what am I missing?

Comment: What events are mutually exclusive here? If A = 1 on first dice and B =1 on second dice then A and B are independent and $A\cap B$ is not {1}, whatever that might mean

Comment: A and B aren't mutually exclusive, I was just giving a condition for $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)
$ to be true. And what do you mean $A \cap B \neq \{1\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't accounted for the fact that there are two dice.  You have to change the sample spaces accordingly.  The sample space for a 1 on the first die is the set of die *pairs* for which the first item is 1, i.e. :

A = { (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6) }

where each pair has a probability of 1/36 (1/6 for each die), totaling 1/6 overall.  Similarly, the sample space for a 1 on the second die is the set of pairs

B = { (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1), (5,1), (6,1) }

So the probability P(A $\cap$ B) is the total probability of { (1,1) }, which of course is 1/36.

Answer (score 0):

Cause u're calculating an intersection of events, not sets of numbers.

Comment: Isn't an event simply a subset of the sample space? In this case, the events would be sets of numbers. What would be the difference between the intersection of events and the intersection of sets of numbers in this case?.

Comment: then ur sets shoud contains not numbers but number pairs like {(1, 1), (1, 2), ... (6, 6)}.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, $(A \cap B) $ refers to the event $\{(1,1)\}$ because both of the events need to happen. It is a cartesian product.

Now, $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P} = \{(1,1)\} = \dfrac{1}{36}$

Therefore, you have that
$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \dfrac{1}{36} = \dfrac{1}{6} *\dfrac{1}{6} = \mathbb{P}(A) \mathbb{P} (B)$